# Wireguard Site-to-Site setup using AWS server and two Raspi Clients

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I was hoping to get some guidance from more experienced users on my planned network setup as I want to reduce the error susceptibility before going "live".

#### Setup & Devices:

```
ServerSite: AWSCloud
    - Server, net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, AWS Firewall set to allow Wireguard Port 51820:
        eth: 174.0.0.1
        wg0: 10.8.0.1: Wireguard tunnel 

ClientSite A:
LAN: 192.168.188.0/24
    - 192.168.188.1: RouterGatewayA, no static routes possible
    - RaspiA, DHCP server with Pihole and WireguardClient, net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
        eth: 192.168.188.2
        wg0: 10.8.0.2
    - 192.168.188.10: WinA, no wireguard client running, Standardgateway 192.168.188.1

ClientSite B:
LAN: 192.168.2.0/24
    - 192.168.2.1: RouterGatewayB, no static routes possible
    - RaspiB, DHCP server with Pihole and WireguardClient, net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
        eth: 192.168.2.2
        wg0: 10.8.0.3
    - 192.168.2.10: WinB, no wireguard client running, Standardgateway 192.168.2.1

RoadWarrior:
LTE via Wireguard Tunnel
```

#### Goal:

- RaspiA and RaspiB are always connected via Wireguard to AWScloud just for internal network traffic. All other traffic (ie. HTTP remains routed via local gateway)
- All LAN-Devices behind the Raspi's are accessible by each other, i.e. WinA is able to get access to WinB without being a client of the Wireguard network itself
- the RoadWarrior is also able to connect to each LAN memeber, i.e. RoadWarrior is able to access WinA

#### Wireguard configs:

```
AWSCloud: Server
    [Interface]
    PrivateKey = <key>  
    Address = 10.8.0.1/32
    ListenPort = 51820
    PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    [Peer]
    #RaspiA
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32, 192.168.188.0/24 (LAN.A traffic),
    #RaspiB
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.3/32, 192.168.2.0/24 (LAN.B traffic)
    #RoadWarrior
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.4/32


ClientSite A: RaspiA
    [Interface]
    PrivateKey = <key>
    Address = 10.8.0.2/24

    PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = my.ddns.example.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24 (Tunnel traffic), 192.168.2.0/24 (LAN.B traffic)
    PersistentKeepalive = 25

ClientSite B: RaspiB
    [Interface]
    PrivateKey = <key>
    Address = 10.8.0.3/24

    PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = my.ddns.example.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24 (Tunnel traffic), 192.168.188.0/24 (LAN.A traffic)
    PersistentKeepalive = 25

Client RoadWarrior
    [Interface]
    PrivateKey = <key>
    Address = 10.8.0.4/24
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = my.ddns.example.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 (All traffic)
    PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

As I am not able to set up static routes on my Client A/B LAN routers, the default gateway can not be set to the Raspi A/B. 
    - Therefore setting up a static Route on WinA to have access to LAN B:

```
route ADD 192.168.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.188.2 //on WinA and every other client in the LAN
route ADD 192.168.188.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.2 //on WinB and every other client in the LAN
```

(use -p to make them survive a reboot / make them persistent)

As I am far away from being a network-expert any help would be highly appreciated! Maybe you can spot some some mistake or ineffieciency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested above and everything is working fine. If someone can spot some routing inefficiencies or even a security breach I would be happy for your feedback!